# Vercel Deploy Error: Missing Dependency I already have?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I got this error when trying to build with vercel

```
Error: No Next.js version could be detected in your project. Make sure `"next"` is installed in "dependencies" or "devDependencies"
```

Despite next being in my dependencies, the app was created with 'create-next-app', i'm not sure at all what to do here can anyone help me out?

Here is my package folder:

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server.mjs",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "next": "^12.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.20.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: This was solved for me by doing away with yarn entirely and instead overriding the vercel build commands with 'npm install' and 'npm run build'.

Comment: You may want to add the solution that worked for you as an answer to your own question.